# OBIEE prompt set: Disable user input in date field

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have a report which contains date prompts. For several reasons, we want to disable manual user input into these date prompts, and to require the use of the date picker instead (this requirement won't change).

How can one do this?

What I've tried:

- adding a javascript snippet (embedded in an invisible text prompt) to disable the text field. This works, however when I click "Apply" in the promptset, the date field is re-enabled!

Any insight on how I can accomplish this?

Anybody know how to hack the behavior of the Apply button so I can call my js function again? OR where can I hack the raw html of the promptset/report so that can set the date fields to "disabled=true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any hack for the "Apply" button, however if we change your process a bit, instead of locking the columns down (and possibly creating confusion for the end user "Why can't I click on this prompt!!"), what we could do is hide the prompts either by using a JQuery function, or other method. The link within this answer describes several options to hide prompts:

1. Hidden prompts (Oracle Method)
2. Hiding prompts using guided navigation
3. Hiding prompts in a section
4. Hiding certain UI controls inside a prompt

This link has many other links to resources, and should hopefully answer your question, albeit in a different way.

Links (several in case one gets broken):

- http://intelligentinsight.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/obiee-11g-hidden-prompts-and-hiding-prompts/ (Main Link)
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e10544/prompts.htm#CIHCDDEG (Oracle Link, should be stable)
- http://intelligentinsight.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/obiee-11g-improve-dashboard-prompt-ui-selectively-hiding-and-displaying-prompts-using-jquery/ (Link with JQuery instruction)

Comment: Thanks MarkP; I'll upvote you when I get the reputation (new account here)

Comment: If this solves your dilemma, you can still accept it as the answer, no matter the rep. If it was helpful, but didn't solve your question, then an up vote is the correct course of action. No Problem. Welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your help with this Mark P-- I will deal with this properly, with feedback/solution/accept once I get time. I've gotten sidetracked for the moment

Comment: Mark P's approach worked. His third link above was the most useful one for me. One can prepend a javascript function to the browserdom.js file (there are multiple copies of this file; find the correct "live" one by a process of elimination). Then you add a call to this function ***in the place where he specifies on that link bold, shown in the notepad graphic***. The js function will then be called every page load; but also every time an "Apply" button is clicked in a report. No screenshots etc. because I can't add them because rep.